# PHP mysql conditional unique constraint?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, sql-insert, database-trigger

How do I make a column will take in only x amount of similar string entries?

Example:

```
------------
| room_type|
|----------|
| premium  |
| premium  |
| premium  |
| premium  |
| premium  |
```

and if there's different type of entry it will only take in x amount of that as well.

Comment: you can use trigger on your database to control that, or create a check on your php before the insert

Comment: Do you want to use an `enum`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot be done with a constraints. You could write `before` triggers for this.

Insert trigger:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger my_insert_trigger before insert on my_table
for each row
begin
    if (select count(*) from my_table where room_type = new.room_type) > 5 then
        signal sqlstate '45000';
    end if;
end;
$$
delimiter ;
```

Update trigger:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger my_update_trigger before update on my_table
for each row
begin
    if (select count(*) from my_table where room_type = new.room_type) > 5 then
        signal sqlstate '45000';
    end if;
end;
$$
delimiter ;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9hDTmz6WDKudrqPMyC9BMm/1)**:

The trigger raises error:

> Error: ER_SIGNAL_EXCEPTION: Unhandled user-defined exception condition